# Tomcat Manager script alternatives

Tags: tomcat

I'm looking for something similar to Tomcat's Manager App for managing application deployment, but on the local Linux command line, so it does not require configuring 'manager-gui' credentials or any credentials.  Just simple scripting of basic installation tasks for deploy, undeploy, and status which could be done from the shell or in python.

We distribute a web app running on Tomcat, and would like to make installation and upgrades a little easier for customers and we can not add a 'manager' username and pwd (esp. in plaintext) from a security perspective.

Comment: Are these scripts intended to run on the same machine that Tomcat is running on?

Comment: Yes, on the same host from the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of Tomcat's automatic deployment. Something along the lines of:

- Download updated WAR to temporary location
- Unpack updated WAR
- Copy any customer specific configuration files from the current WAR (web.xml, context.xml etc.) to the unpacked updated WAR
- Re-pack the updated WAR
- Copy the WAR to the web applications directory

You probably also want to take advantage of Tomcat's [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) and consider configuring Tomcat to remove the old version once it is no longer being used.

Undeploy is as simple as deleting the WAR file.

Status is a little trickier but curl or similar for a known static resource should be sufficient. Better yet, an application specific status page that does all the checks and just reports OK (or not).